# Some problems with divisors...

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have to solve the following exercises, but I don't know I have to start solving them.

1) Find $Cl(\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{A}^{m})$;

2) Find $Cl(X \setminus x)$;

3) Determine $Pic(X)$ where $X$ is the projective curve $y^2=x^3$.

Is there a canonical method to calculate the divisor class group or $Pic(X)$?

Comment: 1) I know that a codimension 1 subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{A}^m$ is given by $G(u_0:\dots:u_n;y_1:\dots:y_m)$ that is homogeneous in the first $n$ coordinates. My problem, now, is to define the degree of a divisor and to show that a divisor is principal if and only if its degree is $0$. So $Cl(\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{A}^m)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Check out Hartshorne's chapter on divisors.

Comment: You  should explain what $X$ is in 2) and in the last question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This is Proposition 6.6 in Hartshorne's book. There's probably an easier way to see this in this case, but I don't know of it.

2) Here we can use Proposition 6.5 in Hartshorne. If $X$ have dimension 2 or greater, then this says that removing $x$ doesn't affect the class group (which is isomorphic to the Picard group if $X$ is nice). Otherwise, if $X$ is a curve, we have an exact sequence $$\mathbb Z \to Cl( X) \to Cl(X \backslash \{x\}) \to 0.$$

I don't know what more you can say. I guess this depoends on torsion in $Cl(X)$, for example.

3) This is computed in [this PDF](https://people.math.osu.edu/castravet.1/MATH518/victor.pdf) file.